# Is it a 'noun' or 'Adverb of place'?

Tags: nouns, parts-of-speech

"The boy went to his house."

Is 'house' from the above sentence a 'noun' or 'Adverb of place' ?

I know the word 'house' is noun but the definition of adverb of place is to answer the question 'Where'

Comment: "House" is a noun, and "his house" is a noun phrase functioning as object of the preposition "to". The whole preposition phrase "to his house" is then complement of the verb "went". Note that goal preposition phrases are complements since they need to be licensed by the verb -- normally, a verb of motion.

Comment: House is a noun. It can never be an adverb. This is clear once you consider if the term *house* could modify the verb *went*. Let's try this on for size:

How did the boy go? House
When did the boy go? House
To what degree did the boy go? House

You get the idea.